# What is exceptional condition pending fd in select function?

Tags: c++, sockets, bsd

The prototype for the select function is

```
select(int no_of_fd,fd_set read_fds,fd_set write_fds,fd_set expection_condition_fd,const struct timeval *timeout)
```

What is that `exception condition fd's` represent?

When those fd will be set ?

Comment: When an error occurs - e.g. when the connection is closed.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: A closed connection would usually signal the *read* fd_set instead of the *exception* fd_set.

Comment: @lgor Tandetnik Is it so?. I think read fds will be set When a client closes it connection. But i am not sure

Answer (score 4):

It is used to:

1. the presence of out-of-band data when `SO_OOBINLINE` is not enabled.
2. detect a non-blocking `connect()` failure on Windows.  If the connection is successful, the socket is put into `write_fds`, otherwise it is put into `except_fds` instead.  This is documented on MSDN for the [`select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141.aspx) function:

   > In summary, a socket will be identified in a particular set when select returns if:
   >
   > readfds:
   >
   > - If listen has been called and a connection is pending, accept will succeed.
   > - Data is available for reading (includes OOB data if SO_OOBINLINE is enabled).
   > - Connection has been closed/reset/terminated.
   >
   > writefds:
   >
   > - **If processing a connect call (nonblocking), connection has succeeded.**
   > - Data can be sent.
   >
   > exceptfds:
   >
   > - **If processing a connect call (nonblocking), connection attempt failed.**
   > - OOB data is available for reading (only if SO_OOBINLINE is disabled).

   In case of a failure, you can query the socket for the particular error code using `getsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR)`, if needed.

   On some other platforms, such as Linux, `select()` always puts the socket into `write_fds` regardless of whether the connection succeeded or failed, you have to query the error code to differentiate.  This is documented on the Linux man page for the [`connect(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) function:

   > RETURN VALUE
   >   If the connection or binding succeeds, zero is returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.
   >   ...
   >   EINPROGRESS
   >   The socket is nonblocking and the connection cannot be completed immediately.  **It is possible to select(2) or poll(2) for completion by selecting the socket for writing.  After select(2) indicates writability, use getsockopt(2) to read the SO_ERROR option at level SOL_SOCKET to determine whether connect() completed successfully (SO_ERROR is zero) or unsuccessfully (SO_ERROR is one of the usual error codes listed here, explaining the reason for the failure).**

Comment: Can you expand on the first point and maybe add a reference ?

Answer (score 1):

The standard calls them [`errorfds`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) but doesn't say what errors exactly should be reported. In practice `errorfds` is not often used for errors. It is used for "exceptions", one of which is out-of-band data - for example the TCP URG mechanism.